# How to properly enumerate object elements in a state array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've begun learning React and have been following along with a tutorial while also experimenting along the way.

Something I was wondering was, if I have a state array containing objects, each of which have a property for their ID #, what is the best/most correct way to enumerate the objects? Below is what I have, which does work:

```
class Counters extends Component {
  i = 0;
  state = {
    counters: [
      /* array of counter objects */
      { id: ++this.i, value: 0 },
      { id: ++this.i, value: 0 },
      { id: ++this.i, value: 0 },
      { id: ++this.i, value: 0 }
    ]
  };
```

I was wondering if this is considered "proper," and if not, what the correct way to do this is.

Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly sure what you’re asking, but are you looking for something like `counters: [0, 0, …].map((value, i) => ({ id: i + 1, value }))`? What needs to happen with the ids when the state changes?

Comment: Question is unclear -- By using `counters: [ {value: 0}, {value: 0}, ... ]` you could consider the counter's array index its "id". If you're adding counters dynamically, you could keep `lastUsedId` in the state, and new counters get id of `state.lastUsedId + 1`.

Comment: @Ry- I think that's what I'm looking for.

The ID's wouldn't change, it's just a way for each object to know it's own index

Comment: @user633183 I actually didn't think of using the index of the element. That would work for this experiment I'm doing, but what I was ideally looking for was a way for each object to have it's own ordered ID number that it could use. No specific reason for it, just wondering if it was possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do is

```
state = { 
    counters: Array(numberOfCounters).fill().map((x, i) => ({id: i, value: 0}))
}
```

```js
console.log(Array(10).fill().map((x, i) => ({id: i, value: 0})))
```